# Odd-logs ratio is too large for linear term?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, ordinal-data, odds-ratio

I have the following glm:

```
glm1 <- glm(formula= cbind(Cat6Score, Cat6Not) ~ Year + Class + Gender,
               data = Framework1, family = "binomial"(link="logit"))
```

Where I am testing the effects of Year, Class and Gender against the score in a test (out of 6). This is what the Cat6Score, Cat6Not means.

I have ran the model, done averaging based on AIC selection, and exponentiated the coefficients to obtain the following:

```
> exp(avcat6)
                  2.5 %      97.5 %    avcat6
(Intercept) 0.007121638  0.01735577 0.01111762
Class.L     2.944732458 10.39905576 5.57793466
Class.Q     0.324129611  1.02739482 0.57706939
Class.C     0.763990853  1.92601185 1.21303563
Class^4     0.941918223  1.98118003 1.36605621
Class^5     0.649417666  1.14487969 0.86226742
Year        1.636622466  2.01896565 1.85699225
GenderM     0.886881151  1.16220699 1.01516098
```

I understand that I am obtaining the confidence intervals for a ratio increase per unit increase in Class, Year and Gender.
I also understand due to Class being an ordered factor (1 to 6), I should take the Class.L for interpretation as this gives a linear trend.

However my question is this:

Why is the odds ratio for class so high? Due to the total score being 6, and my averages being as follows:

```
 Class      Average
1       1 0.08692308
2       2 0.17455696
3       3 0.39405797
4       4 0.35016393
5       5 0.69686869
6       6 0.55545455
```

Why is there a supposed increase of 5.57 per increase in class from the odds ratios when this is not the case according to the averages? I must be going wrong somewhere.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you seem to be trying to interpret a linear term in the presence of higher degree polynomial terms (as evidenced by the .L, .Q, .C, ^4, ^5 suffixes on your coefficients). Don't trust your intuition about what should be reasonable versus not reasonable in this situation. Your odds ratio of 5.57 is interpreted as the relative increase in odds per increase in class **when all other covariates, including the higher order polynomial terms of class, are held constant**. That said, I'm also wondering why are you surprised at this result. From the data you share, there does seem to be an increasing prevalence of your outcome with class, so I would expect odds ratios > 1.

But I have other questions: Why are you using a logistic regression model when the outcome is an integer valued score? I'm surprised that you can even fit this model without errors or warnings at least. Also, how did you arrive at the choice of using a five-degree polynomial? How many observations are in your data?

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
The category score (/6) is made up of 6 individual 0/1s for absence or presence of that mark. This is over 750 individuals, each with a score out of 6. 
So the .L odds ratio is not equivalent to the score increase per 1 unit of class? This is how I had been interpreting it thusfar. It is more a random numerical increase on a log scale which is equivalent to the score increase in some aspect?
The five degree polynomial comes from class being an ordered factor from 1-6.
I used a logistic regression as I am testing numerous predictor variables against the score